# Converting pandas._libs.tslibs.timestamps.Timestamp to seconds since midnight?

Tags: pandas, datetime, timestamp, timedelta

I have a `pandas._libs.tslibs.timestamps.Timestamp` object, e.g., `2016-01-01 07:00:04.85+00:00` and I want to create an `int` object that stores the number of seconds since the previous midnight.

In the above example, it would return `7 * 3600 + 0 * 60 + 4.85 = 25204.85` 
Is there a quick way to do this in pandas?

Comment: "*number of seconds since the previous midnight*" - be aware that if you have a time series that spans multiple days, the "seconds since midnight" parameter will reset to zero whenever the date changes. If that should not be the case, you can set a reference date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`normalize()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Timestamp.normalize.html) to subtract the date part:

```
# ts = pd.to_datetime('2016-01-01 07:00:04.85+00:00')
>>> (ts - ts.normalize()).total_seconds()
25204.85
```

It also works with DataFrame through `dt` accessor:

```
# df = pd.DataFrame({'date': [ts]})
>>> (df['date'] - df['date'].dt.normalize()).dt.total_seconds()
0    25204.85
Name: date, dtype: float64
```

Comment: How would this change if `ts` was a `Series` of pandas Datastamps? I tried your code and it said `AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'normalize'`

Comment: Because you need the `dt` accessor with a `Series` or `DataFrame` if the dtype is `datetime64`

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is what you are looking for but here is an implementation:

```
import pandas as pd

def seconds_from_midnight(date):
    return date.hour * 3600 + date.minute * 60 + date.second + date.microsecond / 1000000

date = pd.Timestamp.now()
print(date)
print(seconds_from_midnight(date))
```